# CMP4 Decoder for DirectShow Filter Graph

Tags: directshow, mp4, decoder

I have  stream  which i have to decode with **CMP4 codec** format...
Anyobe know a CMP4 decoder?

**Note:** 
When I decode stream with standart MP4 decoders such as Elecard  I get an corrupted image...
Which is mainly red green and yellow picture.

Comment: It is a custom `FOURCC` and decoder might only exist from the one who introduced it (Comart Systems?)

Answer (score 0):

CMP4 is a codec from Comart Systems. You can find a Codec Pack on there [download site](http://www.comartsystem.com/EU/SUPPORT/download/patch/). 
With the "Comart Hicap/MIS Codec Pack" or the "Comart ND & Pillar Codec Pack" you should be able to play those files.